# Много SQL запросов за одну транзакцию

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Здравствуйте.

У меня база данных используется чисто для хранения и доставать из неё редко необходимо, всё нужное находится в оперативной памяти. Поэтому выгрузку данных я делаю каждые 15 минут. Но множество `momoko.execute(query)` безжалостно атакуют Postgre сервер. Потом я увидел казалось бы решение: `momoko.transaction([queries])`, но судя по тому, что метод возвращает список курсоров к каждому результату запроса, то данный метод также делает много `momoko.execute`.  Да и в исходном коде тоже похоже что `execute` в цикле, хотя асинхронный код очень трудночитаем для меня.

Так вот вопрос, почему нельзя сделать за один `execute` через точку с запятой все запросы? Вообще возможность такая есть, но об этом нигде не пишут, как будто это дикость и так делать нельзя. А также если передавать один большой запрос, то виснет поток, если через `transaction`, то `gen.corountine` работает как положено.

Comment: Не вижу принципиальной разницы - что так, что этак сервер будет атаковаться множеством запросов, не? На сетевых задержках сэкономить разве что

Comment: Думаете нет разницы практически? Вот мне и интересно знать, стоит ли тысячу запросов делать через ";" или оставлять как есть

Comment: А вы проверьте и напишите об этом статью на каком-нибудь популярном сайте. Или даже журнале.

Comment: Точно, спасибо! Мне как раз статья для магистратуры нужна!) а чем можно проанализировать производительность самой postgresql?